# Is it possible to overload the ~ operator on strings?

Tags: python, string, overloading, operator-keyword

```
>>> a = 55
>>> b = "hello"
>>> ~a  # this will work
>>> ~b  # this will fail
```

No real surprise for the failure above, but suppose I wanted to overload ~ operator to work on strings. I'm fairly new to Python, so I did some digging on this and found a few tantalizing suggestions that I just couldn't get working. I know I can create some kind of new class, but I'd like the following to work as well:

```
>>> ~"alpha bravo"
```

Is this possible? If so, how? How does one do this kind of overload?

Comment: If you're feeling industrious then you can write a front-end that parses the code and modifies the AST as required.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `~'alpha bravo'` to do? Perhaps there's some other data structure (other than a string) that could work for what you want?

Comment: I've been enjoying one recent change to C# that was taken from PHP (which was probably taken from somewhere else) and that's embedding variables inside strings. After it dawned on me that I could fairly easily implement `myformat( "You have {beers} on the wall.")` then I took the mental leap to considering `~"You have {beers} on the wall"`. These are the things one thinks of when trying to learn more about a language.

Comment: [You can have it soon in python 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), it will look like `f"You have {beers} on the wall."`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible in Python.  You can not add new methods to built-in types in a way that will work reliably.

One thing you could do is subclass string, and define the magic method `__invert__`.  But it would not work on string literals, only on instances of your subclass.

Comment: `forbiddenfruit` would not work(I know still not advised...)?

Comment: `forbiddenfruit` can add you the method with a horrible hack, but it will not work via the operator, only when calling directly.

Comment: This is, of course, a bit disappointing. I suspected it wasn't possible, but I didn't know for sure. I figured it was worth asking those with a little more experience. See my note above. Maybe it's something worth suggesting as a future language feature. This principle of formatting output hasn't been lost on other language developers.

Comment: In fact, it's already been done - see [PEP-0498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Comment: Geez... how did I miss that? I don't remember that in any of the tutorials I read. Well, I have something new to go play with.